# What is the function of 'Serial time code message (ToD) (RS-232 serial line)' as provided in a specification of distribution amplifer?

Tags: amplification, gps, time

What is the function of 'Serial time code message (ToD) (RS-232 serial line)' as provided in a specification of distribution amplifer?
http://spectracom.com/products-services/precision-timing/epsilon-switch-amplifier-system

Answer (score 1):

I guess is it about the device's capability of sending a time code (i.e. a formatted and standardized way of communicating information about time) via RS232 serial line.